# Yii2 backend UrlManager not working properly

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-urlmanager

I've got a problem with my backend url manager which is obviously doing different thing then my frontend.

frontend url: `www.example.com/frontend/web/site/index`

backend url: `www.example.com/backend/web/index.php/site/login`

Both urls are working when request like above. But when i call the backend url like frontend without the `index.php`, i just receive 404. Also my site/index is not working, because when i enter it trough `backend/web/index.php/site/index`, i get redirected to `backend/web/index.php/site/login` immediatly. I thinkg those two have the same problem. But it is strange, because both `main.php` are almost equally:

---

**SOLUTION:** Missing `/backend/web/.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

---

**frontend/config/main.php**

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

**backend/config/main.php**

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

I would be glad if someone could help me with this. Please just ask for furth or missing informations.

Comment: You have a different settings for `showScriptName` - set `false` in backend config to remove `index.php` from URLs.

Comment: @rob006 Oh sorry, i forgotten to post them with both `false`. When i switch them, i'm ending up the same.

Comment: Try compare `.htaccess` files in `backend/web` and `frontend/web` - maybe you don't have configured rewrite rules.

Comment: @rob006 Ok now i can enter `backend/web/site/login` without the `index.php`. But still `backend/web/site/index` redirects me to `backend/web/site/login`. I did not change any layout or view so far and my root `.htacces` is empty so far

Comment: Well this is expected - only authorized users should have access to backend panel, so requiring login makes perfect sens.

Comment: Yeah sure. But my `actionIndex` does only render index site, there is no condition pointing to login when logged out yet.

Comment: Default backend `SiteController` from `yii2-app-advanced` has configured `AccessControll` in `behaviors()` to force login in `index` action.

Comment: Alright i didn't know. I was confused that index is even showed as menu item even if it can't be accessed. Thank you very much for the help rob006, wish you a nice night.